# Python 2.7 passing variable into subprocess command line

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, variables

I want to use a variable and pass it on to shell command line. Problem is. I don't know how. Need help.

```
 def gauti():
    imti=tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    subprocess.call("grep -i 'imti' /var/log/syslog > logas.txt", shell=True)
```

Instead of 'imti' I need a variable that would be delivered in python program to be searched in syslog file.

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting

```
subprocess.call("grep -i '{imti}' /var/log/syslog > logas.txt".format(imti=imti), 
                shell=True)
```

or pass array to `call` method with all required parts

```
logas = open('logas.txt', 'a+')
subprocess.call(['grep', '-i', imti, '/var/log/syslog'], stdout=logas)
```